# Unreasonable deadLock detected in multithreading Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, deadlock

I have a code where two thread classes implementing Runnable are running and sharing a common object of class Buffer.

Although I have used synchronized blocks and `wait()` and `notify()` methods correctly within my knowledge, but when I sleep the thread with `Thread.sleep(0)` inside the try/catch block, after some accepted output  result it goes in deadlock.

Problem is not detected when  I sleep the thread Cook with 1000ms that is `Thread.sleep(1000)` and thread Bheem with 3000ms  that is `Thread.sleep(3000)`

This is a common producer-consumer scenario in threading and I intentionally put consumer above the producer.

**P.S. - I have given the *output*  trimmed from the  last. Actual output was pretty big.**

**Below code is in Bheem class**

```
public void consume() {

        while (ob.buffer >= 1) {
            synchronized (ob) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "    started eating Ladoos with currently "
                        + (ob.buffer--) + " ladoos in plate");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(0); // bheem takes 1.5 sec to eat

                    ob.notify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        synchronized (ob) {

            try {
                System.out
                        .println("Plate is empty, bheem will wait for ladoos to serve ");
                ob.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            consume();
        }
    }
```

**This one is in Cook class**

```
public void produce() {

        while (ob.buffer < 5) {
            synchronized (ob) {

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "  started making Ladoos with currently "
                        + (ob.buffer++) + " ladoos in plate");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(0); // 1 sec time taken to make a ladoo

                    ob.notify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        synchronized (ob) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Plate is full, cook will wait ");
                ob.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            produce();
        }

    }
```

*This is the main method calling just for the sake of understanding the viewers*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Buffer b = new Buffer(0);

        Producer p = new Producer(b);
        Consumer c = new Consumer(b);

        Thread producer = new Thread(p, "Cook");
        Thread consumer = new Thread(c, "Bheem");

        System.out.println("Main started");
        // buffer size is taken as 5 max.
        consumer.start(); // bheem takes 1.5 sec to finish a ladoo



        /*try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/


        producer.start(); // cook takes 1 sec to prepare ladoo
```

**Output**

```
Plate is empty, bheem will wait for ladoos to serve 
Cook  started making Ladoos with currently 0 ladoos in plate
Bheem    started eating Ladoos with currently 1 ladoos in plate
Plate is empty, bheem will wait for ladoos to serve 
Cook  started making Ladoos with currently 0 ladoos in plate
Bheem    started eating Ladoos with currently 1 ladoos in plate
Plate is empty, bheem will wait for ladoos to serve 
Cook  started making Ladoos with currently 0 ladoos in plate
Bheem    started eating Ladoos with currently 1 ladoos in plate
Plate is empty, bheem will wait for ladoos to serve 
Cook  started making Ladoos with currently 0 ladoos in plate
Bheem    started eating Ladoos with currently 1 ladoos in plate
Cook  started making Ladoos with currently 0 ladoos in plate
Cook  started making Ladoos with currently 1 ladoos in plate
Cook  started making Ladoos with currently 2 ladoos in plate
Cook  started making Ladoos with currently 3 ladoos in plate
Cook  started making Ladoos with currently 4 ladoos in plate
Plate is full, cook will wait 
Plate is empty, bheem will wait for ladoos to serve
```

Comment: to simplify your life, take a look at primitives provided by `java.util.concurrent` package

Comment: @rkosegi Yes , but even for experimenting there should be some reason for this absurd output.

Comment: Well, atleast one error is that you are reading `ob.buffer` outside of the sync block. Not only can you miss update (unless declared volatile), but also the state in the sync block is not guaranteed.

Comment: Furthermore, your wait condition is not guarded properly. You just enter a wait without knowing the state of the buffer. Waiting should be done inside a sync block under a condition loop (you can have spurious wake ups). I recommend reading the book "concurrency in practice" since there is lot more to it.

Comment: @MPlatvoet I just swapped `while (ob.buffer < 5) {` with 
`synchronized (ob) {` and same in Bheem class as well. Still same deadlock.

Comment: @MPlatvoet Yes, I am thinking the same for the book. I am new in java.

Comment: @MPlatvoet Do you mean using loop condition for invoking wait() method opposite of what I have done ?.

Comment: Yes, see e.g. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/THI03-J.+Always+invoke+wait()+and+await()+methods+inside+a+loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the consumer takes the last ladoo, what prevents your producer from completely filling the plate and calling the last `notify()` *before* the consumer manages to call `wait()`?  Likewise, when the plate becomes full, what prevents the consumer from taking the last ladoo and calling the last `notify()` before the producer enters `wait()`?

A call to `o.notify()` does *nothing* if some other thread is not waiting to receive the notification.  That is to say, the object `o` does not remember that it was notified.

Comment: You mean while jvm shifts from its last iteration  of while loop in Cook class to immediate next synchronized block in Cook class, **between this shift time ** Consumer thread gets awaked from wait state by Cook thread's last accepted while loop iteration's `ob.notify();` and does its 5 iterations, AND THEN  , when immediate next synchronized block in Cook class runs and invokes its wait() method thus releasing the lock,consumer's while condition loop's immediate next synchronized block runs and invokes wait() too resulting in deadlock situation as both are waiting for each other?

Comment: Thats what you are trying to say ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @angrysumit, Yes:  Consumer thread empties the plate, leaves synchronized block, loses its time slice.  Producer thread enters synchronized block, starts filling the plate, calls notify() after each ladoo.  Consumer thread, attempts to enter second synchronized block, can't.  Producer thread leaves synchronized block.  Consumer thread enters second synchronized block, calls wait(), ends up waiting forever.  Consumer thread enters second synchronized block, calls wait(), waits forever.

Comment: so what shall be the solution to avoid this  ?

Comment: @angrysumit, Read about _guarded blocks_ in the Oracle Java Tutorials.  Basically, the entire purpose of wait()/notify() is the implementation of so-called guarded blocks:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html